# Скачивание Media Group при помощи Telebot

Tags: python, telegram

Пишу бота на Telebot (pyTelegramBotAPI) и требуется сохранить изображения по media_group_id.

Answer (score 0):

сохраняем каждую фотографию из альбома отправленного боту

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)

    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
```

Comment: Этот ответ вообще никак не относится к вопросу... Он хочет сказать группу медиа (картинок, музыки, видео) по media_group_id. Ибо телеграмм если боту отправляют несколько фоток регистрирует их как разные фотки, одинаковый у них только media_group_id, и человек спрашивает, как по этому параметру скачать сразу все фотографии. Мне эта информация тоже интересна, но данный ответ не отвечает на вопрос.