# Сохранение всех фото из альбома без message_handler(content_types=['photo'])

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Требуется **скачать все фотографии из альбома** присланного боту **без хэндлера**.

Схема такова:

```
msg = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                    text='Отправьте мне фото. Если их много - альбомом.')
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_docs_photo)


def handle_docs_photo(message):
    print("def handle_docs_photo without handler")
    print(message)
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)
    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
    src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)
     
    <...>
```

но скачивается только одно фото из всего альбома.

> def handle_docs_photo without handler {'content_type': 'photo',
> **'message_id': 5202**, **'media_group_id': '12834502212295226'**, 'photo':
> [{'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUV1-f3sgyRXDN8LQgR_p67x0vzKXeAAJ9rjEbtv4AAUnO7OXQf-7aWnP31ZYuAAMBAAMCAANtAAN9JAMAAR4E',
> 'file_unique_id': '**AQADc_fVli4AA30kAwAB**', 'file_size': 34592, 'width':
> 320, 'height': 320}, {'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUV1-f3sgyRXDN8LQgR_p67x0vzKXeAAJ9rjEbtv4AAUnO7OXQf-7aWnP31ZYuAAMBAAMCAAN4AAN8JAMAAR4E',
> 'file_unique_id': '**AQADc_fVli4AA3wkAwAB**', 'file_size': 81766, 'width':
> 575, 'height': 575}]}}

Однако, помня что я точно отвечал на вопрос как сохранить все фото из альбома, я [нашёл свой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140522/234134):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def handle_docs_photo(message):
    file_info = bot.get_file(message.photo[len(message.photo) - 1].file_id)

    downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)

    src = 'files/' + file_info.file_path
    with open(src, 'wb') as new_file:
        new_file.write(downloaded_file)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Пожалуй, я сохраню это")
```

ага, отличие только в присутствии хэндлера - `@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])`.

если добавить `print(message)` в начало функции с хендлером, я заметил `media_group_id`:

> message_handler(content_types=['photo']) {'content_type': 'photo',
> **'message_id': 5203**, 'date': 1604299630, **'media_group_id':**
> **'12834397040650138'**, 'photo': [{'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUU1-fq27fe6sah0tqAAGKuXnfosiGAgACUK4xG7b-AAFJlcvNRhM_c0P-7BeYLgADAQADAgADbQAD_IICAAEeBA',
> 'file_unique_id': 'AQAD_uwXmC4AA_yCAgAB', 'file_size': 17775, 'width':
> 289, 'height': 320}, {'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUU1-fq27fe6sah0tqAAGKuXnfosiGAgACUK4xG7b-AAFJlcvNRhM_c0P-7BeYLgADAQADAgADeAAD-oICAAEeBA',
> 'file_unique_id': 'AQAD_uwXmC4AA_qCAgAB', 'file_size': 31919, 'width':
> 500, 'height': 553}]}}
>
> message_handler(content_types=['photo']) {'content_type': 'photo',
> **'message_id': 5204**, 'date': 1604299630, **'media_group_id':**
> **'12834397040650138'**, 'photo': [{'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUVF-fq246Nz74NppC_cLY5cN1yTpQAAJRrjEbtv4AAUm3Dd-SjBO6G7mBa5cuAAMBAAMCAANtAAPckwIAAR4E', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADuYFrly4AA9yTAgAB', 'file_size': 26725, 'width':
> 320, 'height': 216}, {'file_id':
> 'AgACAgIAAxkBAAIUVF-fq246Nz74NppC_cLY5cN1yTpQAAJRrjEbtv4AAUm3Dd-SjBO6G7mBa5cuAAMBAAMCAAN4AAPdkwIAAR4E', 'file_unique_id': 'AQADuYFrly4AA92TAgAB', 'file_size': 74506, 'width':
> 600, 'height': 405}]}}

выяснил, что присланные фото альбомом телеграм воспринимает как отдельные сообщения, с одним `media_group_id`, соответственно на каждое фото летит `update` с сервера и хендлер ловит каждый сохраняя фото.

суть в том что мне нужно реагировать на фотографии после определённой функции и вызывать другую после сохранения.

я всеми силами и запросами мучал поисковики, ruSO, искал в истории [pyTelegramBotAPI.talks.ru](https://t.me/pyTelegramBotAPI_talks_ru), но так и не смог понять как работать с `media_group_id` и использовать это для получения всех фото присланных альбомом **без message_handler(content_types=['photo'])**.

Comment: Автор а не пробовали сделать условие если будет media_group_id одинаковое то file_id записать в списке и потом сохранять?

Comment: присланные фото альбомом телеграм воспринимает как отдельные сообщения, с одним `media_group_id`. как получить объект сообщения по `media_group_id`? допустим перебирать все последующие `message_id` на присутствие в них `photo`, но я не нашёл метода получения объекта сообщения по его `id`

Comment: так можно же в словаре хранить `media_group_id` и по нему собирать список `file_id` потом его записывать в файл. Поправьте если не прав.

Comment: приведите ссылку на метод или пример как получить все сообщения с одинаковым `media_group_id`.

Comment: Сорри, я неправильно прочитал результат, думал что выведенный результат с `next_step_handler`, а оказалось результат Автора с `content_types=['photo']`. Не ответите на мои вопросы выше? @d-violet

Comment: Автору могу предложить  отлавливать 1 хендлером все возможные `content_types` и уже в хендлере перебирать.

Comment: на кой мне перебирать если функция в хендлере и так сохраняет все изображения? да и задача у меня сохранить все без хендлера, т.к после сохранения должна выполняться другая функция, которая не должна выполняться после хендлера

Comment: `msg = bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                                    text='Отправьте мне фото. Если их много - альбомом.')
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_docs_photo)


def handle_docs_photo(message):` 
Пробовали принтовать `message` в этой функции `handle_docs_photo`?  Какой результат?

Comment: добавил в вопрос вывод. там тоже содержится `media_group_id`, но в `photo` информация об одном изображении с разными размерами

Comment: @d-violet тогда реализуй 
`def listener(messages):
    """
    When new messages arrive TeleBot will call this function.
    """
    for m in messages:
        if m.content_type == 'text':
            # print the sent message to the console
            print(str(m.chat.first_name) + " [" + str(m.chat.id) + "]: " + m.text)`
Думаю тут должно получиться)

Comment: bot.set_update_listener(listener) записывается после объявления `bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)`

Comment: `bot.set_update_listener(listener)` работает так же как и `handler` - реагирует на все сообщения с указанным типом. суть в том что мне нужно реагировать на фотографии после определённой функции и вызывать другую после сохранения

Comment: так сделайте выборку по `content_type` потом по `media_group_id` и записывайте все последующие `file_id` в список, не?

Comment: окей. пользователь дошёл до шага отправки фото - фото сохранили, выполнили нужную функцию. всё работает как задумывалось. а если пользователь **случайно или специально отправит фото** без шага? опять выполнится **функция** которая **не должна выполняться**.

Comment: ну я для того чтобы пользователь не делал лишних движений которые могут привести к крашу, реализовал степы или поставьте условие если ранее были заполнены такие-то, такие-то поля, то ты его пропускаешь, а если нет, то игноришь.

Comment: @Violet, удалось ли вам найти более рациональный ответ на свой вопрос, а не делать это костылем, как привели ответом ниже? Просто в данный момент стоит такая же задача с `register_next_step_handler`-ом:)

Comment: @DenisRudnitskiy увы, нет. Я остановился на сохранении одного фото, с предупреждением пользователя об этом.

Answer (score 1):

Прилетело сообщение - сохранил фото в `download/{chat.id}/{media_group}/`

Таких сообщений будет `от 1 до 10`.
Пытаться понять какое из них последнее - смысла нет.
Если тебе прилетело фото или группа - значит пользователь свой шаг сделал.
Достаточно среагировать на первое сообщение и ответить на него через небольшой промежуток времени. Для остальных сообщений медиагруппы ответ не требуется.

Я покажу грубый, но рабочий пример

```py
photo_delivered: Set[int] = set()


def say_thanks(user: User):
    if user.id in photo_delivered:
        return
    photo_delivered.add(user.id)

    bot.send_message(user.id, "Спасибо, поехали дальше...")

    remove_user_from_photo_delivered_set_after_n_seconds()


def photo_handler(message: Message):
    ...
    say_thanks(message.from_user)
```

Остаётся не забыть про concurrency и поставить защиту от гонки:

- [для псевдо-асинка от telebot (threading)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#lock-objects)
- [для нормального асинка (asyncio)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#lock)

P.S.: Пример скачивания файла выглядит странно, в [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram) это в 2 строки делается, да и API 5.0 уже выкатили (у telebot последнее обновление было 3 месяца назад)

```py
async def photo_handler(message: Message):
    photo = message.photo.pop()
    await photo.download('/path/to/save')
```

Comment: "Пытаться понять какое из них последнее - смысла нет" - извините, но это как-то не разумно, ибо человек может начать загружать фотки, и у него банально отключится интернет. Загрузится одна или две фотки из 10, это не вариант сохранять только 2 или 3 фотки и просто идти дальше...

Comment: @antipups, получение фото никак не зависит от процесса загрузки. Отправка происходит только после окончательной загрузки отправителем всех фото.