# Как сохранить все изображения из сообщения в телеграмме в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Скачиваю изоражение, присланное боту вот так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def message_post(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        f_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        file_info = bot.get_file(f_id)
        down_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(down_file)
```

Но что делать, если пользователь скинет в одном сообщении 2 изображения? Когда я скидываю 2 изображение сохраняется только первое.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1198860/234134 может ответ натолкнёт вас на решение, я решил костылём - запретил больше одного фото

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что он перезаписывает каждый раз файл "img.jpg" , чтобы сохранить больше файлов, рекомендую использовать uuid , и каждый файл сохранять со случайным именем.
Мой вариант:

```
import uuid
@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['photo'])
def message_post(message): #saving photo
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        f_id = message.photo[-1].file_id
        file_info = bot.get_file(f_id)
        down_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        name = str(uuid.uuid4())
        with open(name + '.jpg', 'wb') as file:
            file.write(down_file)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Сохранено')
```