# Как получить все вложения по media_group_id?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Используя `aiogram` для написания эхо-бота возникла проблема: при использовании стандартных методов получения новых сообщений функция вызывается дважды при отправки, например, группы из двух изображений. Пример:

[image: Пример запуска функции два раза]

Код:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher

token = ''
bot = Bot(token=token)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

async def anything(msg: types.Message):
    await msg.answer('Basic reply')

dp.register_message_handler(anything, content_types=['photo','text'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Я решил эту проблему следующим образом:

```
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.utils import executor
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher

TOKEN = ''

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

flag_group_id = None

async def anything(msg: types.Message):
    global flag_group_id
    if msg.media_group_id and not flag_group_id:
        flag_group_id = msg.media_group_id 
        await msg.answer('Получаю вложения')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        #get attachments by media_group_id
        await msg.answer('Отправляю вложения')
    else:
        if not msg.media_group_id:
            flag_group_id = None
            await msg.answer(msg.text or msg.caption or 'Нет сообщения')

dp.register_message_handler(anything, content_types=['photo','text'])
if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

И появилась следующая: как получить все медиа-вложения по media_group_id?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1202083/234134

Comment: Спасибо тебе большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил благодаря коментарию [@violet](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/234134/violet)

Спасибо еще раз!

```py
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import random

bot = Bot(token = "")
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

photo_delivered: set[int] = set()

async def say_thanks(user: types.User):
    if user.id in photo_delivered:
        return
    photo_delivered.add(user.id)
    
    await bot.send_message(user.id, "Спасибо, поехали дальше...")

async def photo_handler(message: types.Message):
    await say_thanks(message.from_user)
    photo = message.photo.pop()
    await photo.download(f'download/{str(random.randint(1,99))}.jpg')

dp.register_message_handler(photo_handler, content_types=['photo'])
executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```