# Как на сервере сохранить весь альбом фотографий то юзера PyTelegramBotApi?

Tags: python, telebot

Как на сервере сохранить весь альбом фотографий то юзера PyTelegramBotApi? Я могу сохранять только одну фотографию присланную пользователем, но как мне сохранить целый альбом состоящий из 10 или больше фотографий?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1202083/234134

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140522/234134

Comment: я видел эти ответы, но почему то когда я отправляю альбом фотографий он не сохраняет только первую и последнюю фотографию